# An XSS attack is working on Firefox but not on Chrome..Suggest changes to make it work on Chrome

Tags: xss

I am able to inject this:

```
http://domain.com/search/songs/<img src='alert(document.cookie)' onerror='alert(document.cookie)'>
```

to the page HTML.

The onerror event is giving me the cookie on my latest updated Firefox.

But Chrome is sanitizing the HTML to this:

```
<img src="alert(document.cookie)" onerror="">
```

When I try to inject the script tag, the application is somehow sanitizing it.

I dont know if I should share the website on which I found this vulnerability here.

Please suggest me on how to make it work on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, demonstrating an attack under a single browser is sufficient for a penetration testing engagement, unless it's an environment where only Chrome is being used or similar.

That being said, I'm guessing this is a reflected XSS, so it's probably being caught by Chrome's XSS auditor: http://blog.chromium.org/2010/01/security-in-depth-new-security-features.html